# Carrierwave add a watermark to processed images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave, rmagick

Im trying to add a watermark to processed images with below code I got from several resources:

```
def watermark
  manipulate! do |img|
    logo = Magick::Image.read("#{Rails.root}/assets/images/watermarks/watermark.png").first
    img = img.composite(logo, Magick::SouthEastGravity, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
  end
end
```

Only problem is, you guess it, does not work.
I get no errors in log/console whatsoever

This is my method inside my uploaded and called like:

```
def function
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [96, 96]
    process :watermark
  end
end
```

Any thoughts on getting some logs on why this doesn't work? I have the Rmagick gems and Imagemagick installed on my system (OSX) And resizing of images does work correct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just do it this way and it works very fine:

```
# Process files as they are uploaded:
process :resize_to_fill => [850, 315]
process :convert => 'png'
process :watermark

def watermark
  manipulate! do |img|
    logo = Magick::Image.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/watermark.png").first
    img = img.composite(logo, Magick::NorthWestGravity, 15, 0, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
  end
end
```

B.

Comment: Thx a lot that totally works, Just a few different params but I could not get it to work perhaps its was the Orientation and my watermark image placing it out of scope.

Comment: Do you by any change have an idea how I could make the color white less prominent more transparent with this setup? thx!

Comment: this answer is 7 years old. Can anyone give a updated syntex here? Thanks!

Comment: I thought the code was outdated until I start to use rmagick gem, instead of mini-magick gem. The code works perfectly with rmagick gem!