# Watermarking with MiniMagick

Tags: imagemagick, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-4.2, minimagick

### Versions:

- Ruby 2.2.3
- Rails 4.2.4
- mini_magick: 4.2.10
- Carrierwave 0.10.0

### Description

I am trying to create a watermarker for a small gallery using CarrierWave as uploader.

I want the watermark to be sized compared to the current image. Therefore I am trying to use a .svg-file with different opacities and a transparent background.

I am using a watermarker based on [Carrierwave add a watermark to processed images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184768/carrierwave-add-a-watermark-to-processed-images)

```
require 'mini_magick'

class Watermarker
  def initialize(original_path, watermark_path)
    @original_path = original_path.to_s
    @watermark_path = watermark_path.to_s
  end    

  def watermark!(options = {})
    options[:gravity] ||= 'SouthEast'

    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(@original_path)
    watermark = MiniMagick::Image.open(@watermark_path)

    result = image.composite(watermark, 'png') do |c|
      c.gravity options[:gravity]
    end
    result.write @original_path
  end
end
```

And calling this as a `process` from my uploader.

## My problems:

1. I cannot get the watermarker to input the picture with transparent background. I played around with:

   - https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick#composite
   - http://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php

   But no progress.
2. I cannot adjust the size of the overlay image properly. There is a lot of settings for the [`geometry`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#geometry) command but I'm stuck.

Any ideas and help would be great.

Comment: That one doesn't cover using .svg, transparency or resizing the overlay.

Comment: Please check this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184768/carrierwave-add-a-watermark-to-processed-images

Comment: Sorry I don't speak Ruby, but... try creating the watermark as a PNG file rather than an SVG - or failing that, try updating your `svg` delegate or replacing it with `rsvg`. Try `watermark.resize()` with a smallish size, then if that works, try getting the size of the original image and using a percentage of that for the `resize()`.

Comment: Gonna try out converting to PNG, how should I do lossless resize?